# OPENCV face detection Exception thrown: read access violation. this->cc.**_Ptr** was nullptr. error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I am using c++ opencv and want to detect faces therefore i wrote this code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>

#include<iostream>

#using namespace cv;


#using namespace std;




void main() {


string path = "C:\\Users\\Gökhan\\Desktop\\Resources\\ test.png";


Mat img = imread(path);



CascadeClassifier faceCascade;


faceCascade.load("C:\\Users\\Gökhan\\Desktop\\Resources\\ 
haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");



if (faceCascade.empty()) { cout << "XML file not loaded" << endl; }


vector<Rect> faces;


faceCascade.detectMultiScale(img, faces, 1.1, 20); //this lines gives the error


for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    rectangle(img, faces[i].tl(), faces[i].br(), Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
}

imshow("Image", img);


waitKey(0);
}
```

However, it is saying that Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFD09F8E6C in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000003537D9F430. and when I click continue it says Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->cc.**_Ptr** was nullptr.

I have not solve this problem. What should I do?

Comment: You are running this in a debugger which will tell you which line of your own code called the code that failed. It will also tell you the value of each item on that line. Check them for nulls yourself, and if still stuck, please edit your question to tell us which line it failed on so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I have editted.

Comment: Very well. ```faceCascade``` cannot be null, and ```faces``` looks like an output, so most likely ```img``` is not correctly initialized. Does ```imread``` have a means to report errors/failure to read and can you check it?

Comment: I changed the path  with another picture but something didn't change. What do you mean by " a means to report errors/failure to read" and how can I check?

Comment: I do not know OpenCV - the documentation should help. A quick search shows that 'If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).' which sounds poor (I'd like it to explain precisely what the error is) but you could check for not-null data.